# Prove that if the trace of a $2\times 2$ matrix over $\mathbb{R}$ is $0$, then it is a linear combination of matrices of the form $XY-YX$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Prove that if the trace of a $2\times 2$ matrix over $\mathbb{R}$ is $0$, then it is a linear combination of matrices of the form $XY-YX$, where $X$ and $Y$ denote arbitrary $2\times 2$ matrices over $\mathbb{R}$.

I understand that for the trace to be $0$ for a matrix

$$ \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     a & b \\
     c & d
  \end{array} \right]
$$

either $a=-d$ or $a=d=0$.
Trying to work backwards by finding an arbitrary $XY-YX$ for any matrix by brute force hasn't proved useful for me so far. Perhaps there's a better solution?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Notice that your second case ($a = d = 0$) is subsumed by the first. Hint: is the set of traceless matrices a subspace?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try computing $XY-YX$ when $X$ and $Y$ are very simple matrices; say matrices with only one nonzero component.  What matrices can you produce this way?  What matrices do you get when you take linear combinations of these matrices?